# regular expression for inserting something before what is matched

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to know the regular expression for inserting characters BEFORE the matched characters from the Regular Expression. For example:

```
var string = "HelloYouHowAreYou"
var regEx = /[A-Z\s]/g    //to identify capital letters, but want to insert a dash before them
string = string.replace(regEx,"-")
console.log(string)
```

How can I accompish this?

Comment: Why did you include `\s` in character class if you want to match capital letters only?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: I wanted to use it for spaces and capital letters, but my question was only referring to the capital part.

Comment: @Mozar: There are basic rules for asking questions ([How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Your question sounds like you have not tried anything to solve the issue (you could mention you tried to use backreferences, like *I used `$1`, but it only resulted in <description>*), so people might think it a poor question. SO users are also very subjective. Don't give up, good people outnumber the other side here :)

Comment: It is usually enough to describe 1) the closest attempt or 2) the latest attempt - with a short description what that gives you and what is still missing. No need to enumerate everything, long questions are also not so welcome. Your question seems OK for me, just that bit I mentioned in the previous comment would make it even more complete/valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `$&` backreference in the replacement pattern to refer to the whole match:

```js
var string = "HelloYouHowAreYou"
var regEx = /[A-Z\s]/g;
string = string.replace(regEx,"-$&")
console.log(string)
```

If you want to avoid matching the uppercase ASCII letter at the beginning of the string, add a `(?!^)` at the beginning:

```js
var string = "HelloYouHowAreYou"
var regEx = /(?!^)[A-Z\s]/g;
string = string.replace(regEx,"-$&")
console.log(string)
```

Note that `\s` matches whitespace. If you want to only match uppercase ASCII letters, use

```
/[A-Z]/g
```

Comment: Downvotes without disclosing the reason do not enrich anyone's knowledge. If anyone knows the reason for this downvote, please let me know how this answer can be improved.

Comment: I do believe 2 lookarounds are too much for the current task. The original question sounding as *regular expression for inserting something before what is matched* just requires a `.replace(regEx,"-$&")` answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a positive lookahead, which looks for the specified characters, but not insert it into the match group and prevent the first character to get a dash at the beginning of the string.

```
/(?!^)(?=[A-Z])/g
```

```js
var string = "HelloYouHowAreYou",
    regEx = /(?!^)(?=[A-Z])/g;

string = string.replace(regEx, "-");
console.log(string);
```

Comment: A single lookahead is enough. No need for dot.

Comment: More, there is no need of a lookaround at all.

Comment: There is a need actually. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it's a more philosophical question to include a character and replace it, or not include it and add a string to the replacement without the search character.

Answer (score 0):

Wiktor Stribiżew has a great answer already, but you can also pass a function to the replace method if you want to do additional manipulation of the string.

```
    var string = "HelloYouHowAreYou"
    var regEx = /[A-Z\s]/g    //to identify capital letters, but want to insert a dash before them
    function replacer(match) {
      return ('-') + (match);
    }
    string = string.replace(regEx,replacer)
    console.log(string)
```